# How to refer to enclosing instance from C++ inner class?

Tags: c++, this, inner-classes

In C++, an object refers to itself via `this`.

But how does an instance of an inner class refer to the instance of its enclosing class?

```
class Zoo
{
    class Bear 
    {
        void runAway()
        {
            EscapeService::helpEscapeFrom (
                this, /* the Bear */ 
                ??? /* I need a pointer to the Bear's Zoo here */);
        }
    };
};
```

**EDIT**

My understanding of how non-static inner classes work is that `Bear` can access the members of its `Zoo`, therefore it has an implicit pointer to `Zoo`. I don't want to access the members in this case; I'm trying to get that implicit pointer.

Comment: Do you come from Java? If so, don't use nested classes like this, because if you create an instance of `Zoo` it will not have an instance of `Bear` as member,as you might think

Comment: I'm familiar with inner classes in Java, but never use them in C++. Is my understanding correct, that `Bear` can access members of `Zoo`?

Comment: If there were a `Zoo` object, it would have access rights to private variables of Zoo. But you need to explictly provide and create a `Zoo` object, and give it to your `Bear` functions as a parameter. The only reason to use nested classes like this in C++ is encapsulation, as the inner class has no implicit access to members of the outer class. Just don't do it, unless you are sure you need it

Comment: @TonythePony: inner classes in C++ are equivalent to static inner classes in Java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unlike Java, inner classes in C++ *do not* have an implicit reference to an instance of their enclosing class.

You can simulate this by passing an instance, there are two ways :

pass to the method :

```
class Zoo
{
    class Bear 
    {
        void runAway( Zoo & zoo)
        {
            EscapeService::helpEscapeFrom (
                this, /* the Bear */ 
                zoo );
        }
    };
};
```

pass to the constructor :

```
class Zoo
{
    class Bear
    {
        Bear( Zoo & zoo_ ) : zoo( zoo_ ) {}
        void runAway()
        {
            EscapeService::helpEscapeFrom (
                this, /* the Bear */ 
                zoo );
        }

        Zoo & zoo;
    };
};
```

Comment: doh someone fix my answer please. For some reason I can not format the code :(

Comment: Thanks... could I also add a method `Zoo self() { return this; }` in `Zoo`, and then call `helpEscapeFrom(this,self())` from `Bear`?

Comment: @Jen No, you need an instance of Zoo

Comment: @VJo: I have also suffered the code formating failure when inside a list. You can do as @DeadMG did (remove the list) or you can alternatively add a single `.` after two new-lines in the list: ` 1 - blah blah\n\n.\n\n    code` It will take somehow more screen real state but will enable code formatting and keep the list.

Answer (score 9):

Inner classes are not special, and don't have any link to their outer class built-in. If you want to access the outer class, then pass a pointer or reference, just as you would with any other class.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the outer class instance from an inner class instance by using offsetof.
This has zero overhead compared to the pointer/reference solution.
It's a bit dirty but it gets the job done.
For example:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct enclosing {
    struct inner {
        enclosing& get_enclosing() {
            return *(enclosing*)((char*)this - offsetof(enclosing, i));
        }
        void printX() {
            std::cout << get_enclosing().x << '\n';
        }
    } i;
    int x;
};
int main() {
    enclosing e;
    e.x = 5;
    e.i.printX();
}
```

P.S.
offsetof makes some assumptions about the type. In C++98 the type has to be a POD and in C++11 the type has to be "standard layout".
Here's a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/

Comment: This is what I had in mind when searching for the same question as OP, but how "safe" is it? Could it be, that for some compilers it won't work, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

An inner class has access to all members of the outer class, but it does not have an implicit reference to a parent class instance.

To answer your modifed Q:
No you cannot access that implicit pointer. I believe one can do so in Java but not in C++.

You will have to pass the outer class object explicitly through constructor or some other function to acheive this.

Technically as per ***C++03 standard(sec 11.8.1)***, a nested class does NOT have special access to its enclosing class.

But there is also this standard defect: openstd.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45  Not sure if this is closed.

Comment: A inner class does _not_ have access to members of the outer class

Comment: Now reading your answer again, I see that you talking about access rights of members from the outer class in a function of from inner class and not the implicit access. That was easy to misunderstand before you clarified it

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in mechanism to achieve this. You need to provide the pointer yourself, via constructor or some kind of SetParent function.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard says (section 11.8.1 [class.access.nest]):

> The members of a nested class have no
>   special access to members of an
>   enclosing class, nor to classes or
>   functions that have granted friendship
>   to an enclosing class; the usual
>   access rules (clause 11) shall be
>   obeyed. **The members of an enclosing
>   class have no special access to
>   members of a nested class**; the usual
>   access rules (clause 11) shall be
>   obeyed.

(emphasis by me).

This means that there is no special relationship between the nested and enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicitly created instance of the enclosing class when creating an instance of the nested class. It has to be done manually.