# How to access parent methods from embedded class in PIMPL pattern

Tags: c++

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198224/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-instance-from-c-inner-class), but my intent is little different.

class B is the embedding class while class A is the embedded class. I want to let B::A have access to member functions of class B. I have seen compilation errors through g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2. The detailed errors are as follows:

```
~/Documents/C++ $ g++ embed.cpp 
embed.cpp:5:7: error: ‘B’ has not been declared
embed.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
embed.cpp:10:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B::A’
embed.cpp:14:9: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B::A’
```

Is there a way that I can make it work?
Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
  B() : impl(new B::A(this)) {}
  ~B(){}

private:
  class A; // want to hide the implementation of A
  A* impl;
};

class B::A
{
public:
  A(B* _parent) : parent(_parent) {} // let embedded class A has access to this parent class
  ~A() { parent = NULL; }

  B* parent;
};

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solved easily if you follow the convention of having the header in one file and the implementation in another.

In file `b.h`:

```
class B
{
public:
  B();
  ~B();

private:
  class A; // want to hide the implementation of A
  A* impl;
};

class B::A
{
public:
  A(B* _parent);
  ~A();

  B* parent;
};
```

In file `b.cpp`:

```
B::B(void)
    :impl(new A(this))
{

}

//other methods and such
```

My compiler was giving me a different error: in the constructor for `B`, you were default-constructing an object that had no default constructor (because it's an incomplete class). The solution is to implement the `B` constructor after class `A` has been fully defined, and the header/implementation separation is a natural way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the definition from the declaration:

```
class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

private:
    class A; // want to hide the implementation of A
    A* impl;
};

// define class B::A

B::B() : impl(new B::A(this)) { }
B::~B() { }
```

By the time you need to *call* `B::A::A()`, it'll already be defined.

You could separate this into three files, `B.hpp`, `BA.hpp` and `B.cpp`, and you would only need to ship `B.hpp` to the client.

Answer (score -1):

You just can't. If you want to use A, then you have to know all about A. But there maybe another approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
  B() : impl(newA()) {}
  ~B(){}

private:
  static Abase *newA();
  class Abase{}; // want to hide the implementation of A
  Abase* impl;
  friend class A;
};
```

And you define you `class A : B::Abase` in another file, and implement `B::newA()` to return a pointer to `A`.

Code not tested.