# Recycling member functionality without inheritance

Tags: c++

There is an interesting template presented on Wikipedia for [Properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)#C.2B.2B).

This template provides something interesting, in that it allows providing logic around member accesses. Building on this, we could easily build something like this:

```
struct Ranged { 
  ranged_property<float,0,1> unit_property; 
};
```

Where the range of `unit_property` is enforced to be within [0,1].

How can we provide a similar functionality the depends on the hosting class' members? For example:

```
struct AdjustableRanged { 
  float max; 
  ranged_property<float,0,max> influenceable_property; 
};
```

Where the range of `influenceable_property` is affected by the value of `max`. Keep in mind, the goal is for this kind of template to be recycled across many vastly different classes. Related concepts are mixins and decorators.

It can be done with macros... but I feel like there *must* be a better more idiomatic C++ solution.

---

Edited to add: I think this could be done by saving a reference to the member inside the ranged_property template... but that seems to be a complete waste of space for what would be effectively a constant value;  **ETA**; A const reference may serve the purpose actually, however, I need to do the investigation.

Comment: Why would you want `max` to be a separate data member in `AdjustableRange`, rather than encapsulating it as a member of the `ranged_property` object (then stipulating it to the constructor)?

Comment: I am not sure a reference would waste space. It is implementation-defined how references are actually realized, but ultimately, they are just *another name* for the same object, so there might not be any visible change in compiler output compared to using the original variable name. Maybe, someone who is more informed about major compilers' inner workings can comment on this...

Comment: Templates are compile-time constructs, they can't be initialised with run-time values.

Comment: He was talking about "similar functionality" and I bet the `ranged_property<float,0,max>` was meant as pseudo-code. That interpretation is also supported by the reference thinking. So it could also be a `ranged_property<float> influenceable_property;`, where `influenceable_property` is initialized with `(0,max)`/`(0,&max)` or the like...

Comment: I think actually the title/tagging is too constrained -- What I'm interested in is the recyclable functionality that depends on a member. In my *particular* usecase, I want these members to define no space if possible, as all the data they use will be contained in the parent class. I will have to do some investigation, as @Oguk may be right that a reference will give me what I want. I'll edit the title a bit.

Comment: @Oguk Thinking on this further, I don't think it's possible for the compiler to successfully elide the reference.

Comment: Maybe you are right, because it cannot resolve the reference at compile time... what about a pointer to member as a template argument?

Comment: @Oguk Looks like no -- based on experimentation (and then reading here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) template parameters cannot point to non-static members. Hilariously, it looks like I'm being railroaded into macros.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Of course you cannot pass a pointer to a member variable of a particular instance (because that's a runtime thing). But that is not a "pointer to member", it's just an ordinary pointer. With a pointer to member, it works: [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6a92a18fc6ba6eb). Or did I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: @Oguk That does in fact work; I am now convinced that what I want is impossible from a memory standpoint. I would submit this as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on our discussion in the comments, it seems the functionality can be achieved with a pointer-to-member template parameter like this (but see the caveats below):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename C, typename T, T C::*m>
struct PrintMember {
    C& obj;
    PrintMember(C& obj) : obj(obj) {};
    void print() { std::cout << "Member of containing class: " << obj.*m << std::endl; };
};

struct TestClass {
    int data;
    PrintMember<TestClass, int, &TestClass::data> pm;
    TestClass() : pm(*this){};
};

int main()
{
    TestClass tc;
    tc.data = 5;
    tc.pm.print();
}
```

This only demonstrates that it is possible to access members of the containing object. There are a few things that this approach doesn't solve:

- If you really only want to access *one* member, it's not worth it, since you have to save a reference to `*this` in the PrintMember member to be able to dereference the pointer to member. So it doesn't actually solve the problem of having to store a reference. You could just as well pass a reference to the member variable itself in the constructor. However, if you need to access multiple members, this allows you to only store *one* reference (to `*this`) and still access all of them.
- Specifying the template arguments of `PrintMember` and initializing the `PrintMember` member variable with `*this` in the constructor is tedious. Maybe, some clever template argument deduction can help here, but I haven't tried yet and I am not even sure it would get any simpler...

In some special cases, there might be dirty ways to get access to the "this" pointer of the enclosing class without saving it explicitly, like the answer using `offsetof` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573810/3749537), but my feeling tells me you wanted something portable and less brittle...