# C++ lambda, not seeing function and argument?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

I have some code using a wrapper class around `std::thread`, which is using a timer struct (based upon `boost::asio`), to call `methodToCallEachIteration()` every 5000 milliseconds:

```
class OurThreadWrapperClass{
    OurThreadWrapperClass(boost::asio::io_service& = generic_timer_queue_s());
};

class A {
    A() : thread1(_TimerIOService){
        thread1.setInterval(5000);
        // This sets the callback function, to be called every INTERVAL ms.
        thread1.start([this](OurThreadWrapperClass&) {
            this->methodToCallEachIteration();
        });
    }

    void callAFunctionHere(std::bitset<10> arg) {
        // ...
    }

    void methodToCallEachIteration() {
        // ...
    }

    struct TimerService {
        constexpr static const size_t num_threads{2};

        TimerService(){
            for(auto& t: _threads){
                t = std::thread([this](){
                    boost::asio::io_service::work keepalive{_ioservice};

                    callAFunctionHere(_anArgument);  // The method and arg not recognised

                    (void)keepalive;
                    _ioservice.run();
                });
            }
        }

        operator boost::asio::io_service&() {
            return _ioservice;
        }

        boost::asio::io_service _ioservice{num_threads};
        std::thread _threads[num_threads];
    };

    OurThreadWrapperClass thread1;
    TimerService _TimerIOService;
    std::bitset<10> _anArgument;
};
```

The problem I am having is that I would like to call `callAFunctionHere()`, from within the TimerService which prepares the threads. I cannot move this function inside TimerService. However, the compiler is complaining that it cannot find `callAFunctionHere()` or `_anArgument`:

```
error: cannot call member function callAFunctionHere(std::bitset<10>) without object

error: 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = TimerService::TimerService()::__lambda19; _Args = {}]', declared using local type TimerService::TimerService()::__lambda19', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
```

I think I need to alter the lambda in `A::A()` so that the compiler can "see" the method and argument but I am not too sure how?

Comment: [how-to-refer-to-enclosing-instance-from-c-inner-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198224/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-instance-from-c-inner-class)

Comment: You may want to rethink your encapsulation here. The functionality of `A` and `TimerService` seem to be confused, and if the intent is for the functionality in `TimerService` to be re-usable across other classes, than making it a nested class of `A` seems redundant.

Comment: BTW `thread1` is constructed before `_TimerIOService` so you are passing an uninitialized object to the constructor of `thread1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lambda that is calling `callAFunctionHere`, the `this` that is captured is the one for the instance of `class A::TimerService`, but you are trying to implicitly use members of an `class A` instance. You need a reference to an object of type `A`, and use that object's members.

```
class A {
    A() : _TimerIOService(this), thread1(_TimerIOService){
        //...
    }
    //...
    struct TimerService {
        A *a_;
        constexpr static const size_t num_threads{2};

        TimerService(A *a) : a_(a) {
            //...
    //...
    TimerService _TimerIOService;
    OurThreadWrapperClass thread1;
    std::bitset<10> _anArgument;
};
```

Notice that `_TimerIOService` needs to come before `thread1`.
And now, the lambda in `A::TimerService` uses `a_` to access the desired members.

Comment: Hi, isn't the A object being passed in during the lambda call from the A ctor? The [this] bit?

Comment: That 'this' is not relevant with 'this' in TimerService.

Comment: `class A` and `class A::TimerService` are two different types, and do not have any implicit relationship with each other. Defining `TimerService` inside `A` simply scopes the class name. There is no notion of an inner instance of an inner class having any sort of access to the containing class that defines the class.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example how the Timerservice part would accept the lambda change?

Comment: I would change `TimerService::TimerService()` to take an `A` pointer or reference and store that reference inside the `A::TimerService` itself.

Comment: @jxh Would I need to change the t = std::thread([this](){ near the thread loop?

Comment: @jxh I'm having a little difficult declaring TimerService to take the argument this. Should it be TimerServer _TimerIOService; and then pass this via A's constructor initialiser list?

Comment: Downvote: `this` in a constructor. That's risky, but you *know* that he's dereferencing the value, invoking functions on it and passing it to thread functions...

Comment: @kfsone: Thanks for the downvote. The risk is already present since `this` is passed to the lambda as the callback of a thread. A redesign may be warranted, but is not required to explain why the original code is not working.

Comment: No, the risk wasn't present - there's a difference between using `this` as an initializer and using it inside the body of the constructor. The `A* this` you are passing to `TimerService::TimeService` is a pointer to a partially constructed object, which he is then going to call `aptr->callAFunctionHere()` and so forth with.

Comment: Especially, see the different behavior between these two pieces of code (I changed the order of declaration of the members of A): http://ideone.com/KLnn62 and http://ideone.com/rGeFG6

Comment: @kfsone: You are assuming that this is the OPs complete implementation, and not some already simplified version. The real version may already take care of any synchronization issues between main thread and sub-threads in terms of object initialization issues. I generally don't assume what is being attempted is wrong unless it is obviously wrong. If I can imagine a situation where the the OP code is correct, I won't normally suggest a change in design unless the question asks for one.

Comment: I'm assuming that someone with a Java-like understanding of class nesting who is unclear how to pass a this pointer to a constructor is unlikely to be aware of the difference between initialization and construction and the risk of the solution you suggest resulting in UB.

Comment: @kfsone: And that's fine. I never asked you to change your vote. I am just saying I generally assume the OP has a reason for doing things the way they are doing it, and I focus the answer around the asked problem.

Answer (score 1):

As always, break the problem down to the MVCE:

```
class A {
    void callAFunctionHere() {}

    struct TimerService {
        TimerService() {
            callAFunctionHere();
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A::TimerService ts;
}
```

http://ideone.com/lEUCvO

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'A::TimerService::TimerService()':
prog.cpp:6:35: error: cannot call member function 'void A::callAFunctionHere()' without object
             callAFunctionHere();
```

This particular error is telling you that, due to name resolution, the compiler can tell that you're trying to access the function/member of the outer scope (`class A`), but you're doing it from the context of an *instance* of the inner (`class A::TimerService`).

This line of code:

```
 callAFunctionHere(_anArgument);
```

is written inside `A::TimerService::TimerService()`, so the `this` pointer is `(A::TimerService*) this` and the code expands to:

```
 A::callAFunctionHere(A::_anArgument);
```

`this` can't be applied to either of those, since there is no direct inheritance or conversion between `A` and `A::TimerService`.

The classes are nested for *naming purposes*, like a `namespace`, but they are otherwise discrete: just because `TimerService` is declared inside of `A` does not connect their instances outside of name scoping: *it does not establish an inheritance or conversion relationship*.

Perhaps what you were trying to do was create a generic `TimerService` class which could describe re-usable functionality via inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TimerService
{
    virtual void handleTimerEvent() = 0;

    TimerService()
    {
    }

    void trigger()
    {
        handleTimerEvent();
    }
};

class A : public TimerService
{

    const char* m_name;

public:
    A(const char* name_) : TimerService(), m_name(name_) {}

    void handleTimerEvent() override
    {
        std::cout << "Handling timer event in " << m_name << '\n';
    }
};

void triggerEvent(TimerService& service)
{
    service.trigger();
}

int main()
{
    A a("A instance 'a'"), b("A instance 'b'");
    triggerEvent(b);
    triggerEvent(a);
}
```

http://ideone.com/92aszw

Comment: Hi, is there a way of fixing the above code so TimerService can hold a pointer to A?

Comment: You could but it wouldn't make much sense. In the above example an instance of `A` is an instance of `TimerService` with additional `A`-specific things. So you don't need a pointer to `A`, just use `virtual` functions to call anything that `TimerService` isn't supposed to provide and them implement them in `A`. Now, `TimerService` can reference those functions without providing an implementation, and at run time the object instance will provide the right functions - as demonstrated. See `handleTimerEvent`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you are trying to separate `TimerService` from `A`. Your other option would be to just make all of this one class. `boost::asio` and the thread system don't care what you *call* your class.

Comment: Here's a more comprehensive example of using a base class to describe a concept that the implementation fulfills: http://ideone.com/5Wy1ce. I would encourage you to read up on classes, inheritance, encapsulation, virtual functions, pointers and references before you continue with your threading challenge. Your code seems to suggest that you are coming from another language, perhaps C, and that you've understood C++ to be similar to said other language in a way that it just isn't.